# Remove eclipse plugin from command line

Tags: eclipse

After upgrading ubuntu, Eclipse has been upgraded to 3.8.
Now, Eclipse does not start anymore. I know that at least one plugin is not compatible with 3.8. But I don't know how to remove it, without the GUI.

So, how can I remove a plugin from the command line?
The log of eclipse can be found here:
http://pastebin.com/8xEK58NL

Comment: by "Eclipse has been upgraded" you mean - **you** upgraded it, right? are you running a 64bit OS? collisions between a 64bit JVM and a 32bit eclipse distribution (installed absently) could cause this, as mentioned [here](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=663734). try and add `-Djava.library.path=/usr/lib/jni` to the VM arguments listed in **eclipse.ini** and see if that does it.

Comment: one more - if that doesn't help, try and remove the **~/.eclipse** directory altogether, as old files from previous installations may be kept there and interfere with newly installed versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this case proved to be really simple.
Since the eclipse plugin that was giving errors was installed through the package manager, I could obviously also uninstall it there.
Removing it, fixed the problem.